# Need to have a single instance of a dependency container exist for a WCF service

Tags: wcf, ioc-container

The idea is to use DI container on my service contract implementation to instantiate my Business and Data classes.

The reason I need to do it this way, is that I have one service contract that deals with different client requests. Each client request corresponds to different Business class

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good idea. [Implementing custom ServiceHostFactory, ServiceHost and IInstanceProvider does the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service/2455039#2455039).

Comment: Forgot to mention the services will be hosted on IIS. Is it still possible to use your suggestion ass is?

Comment: Yes, follow the link and read all about it. The key is to register the custom ServiceHostFactory in you .svc file.