# WCF and Unity - Dependency Injection

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to hock up WCF with dependency injection. All the examples that I have found is based on the assumptions that you either uses a .svc (ServiceHostFactory) service or uses app.config to configure the container. Other examples is also based on that the container is passed around to the classes.

I would like a solution where the container is not passed around (not tightly coupled to Unity). Where I don't uses a config file to configure the container and where I use self-hosted services.

The problem is - as I see it - that the ServiceHost is taking the type of the service implementation as a parameter so what different does it do to use the InstanceProvider?

The solution I have come up with at the moment is to register the ServiceHost (or a specialization) an register a Type with a name ( e.g. `container.RegisterInstance<Type>("ServiceName", typeof(Service);`).

And then `container.RegisterType<UnityServiceHost>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<Type>("ServiceName")));` to register the ServiceHost.

Any better solutions out there? I'm I perhaps way of in my assumptions.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Constructor Injection** to wire up your service implementation, just like you would with any other class.

[Here's a writeup on how to make WCF understand Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service/2455039#2455039).

The example in that answer demonstrates **Poor Man's Injection**, but you can extrapolate from it and set up your UnityContainer instance in the ServiceHostFactory instead of a hard-coded dependency.

You pass the container instance all the way to the custom IInstanceProvider. Now you can use the container in the GetInstance method:

```
public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    var serviceType = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType;
    return this.container.Resolve(serviceType);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't like passing around the container. I will try using generics instead.

Comment: At what point in time is the GetInstance called on the InstanceProvider? When I open the service host?

Comment: You would only be passing the container around in those three WCF classes (ServiceHostFactory, ServiceHost and IInstanceProvider). That's hardly the Service Locator anti-pattern - it's just DI infrastructure. You could even create a general-purpose library that wraps around Unity. Castle Windsor's WcfFacility does just that. To answer your other question: GetInstance is called every time a service operation is invoked.