# WCF service with ninject extension

Tags: wcf, web-services, ninject

i got problem with my wcf service with ninject extension. When my service doesnt have parameterless constructor when im trying to call it i got error that im missing it, when i got parameterless  constructor:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class ContractService: IContractService
{
 public ContractService()
        : this(new AddressService(), new TelephoneService())
    {

    }
    [Inject]
    public ContractWCFService(IAddressService addressService, ITelephoneService telephoneService)
    {

        _addressService = addressService;
        _telephoneService = telephoneService;
    }...
}
```

then, parameterless one is called and i think the second one with attribute [Inject] should be called.

Edit : NinjectWebCommon:

```
  private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();

        kernel.Bind<IAddressService>().To<AddressService>().InHttpRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<TelephoneService>().To<TelephoneService>().InHttpRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).InHttpRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind(typeof(EFModel)).ToSelf().InHttpRequestScope();
        IoC.Initialize((StandardKernel)kernel);


    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For passing parameters / managing your instance with ninject, you should combine  [Instance Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 
and / or specific ninject [extenstion](http://nuget.org/packages/CommonInstanceFactory.Extensions.Wcf.Ninject/).

This post can be also helpful: [Passing parameters to a WCF ServiceHost type with Ninject 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733219/passing-parameters-to-a-wcf-servicehost-type-with-ninject-2)