# Wcf dependency injection

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

I have an IService.

It is implemented by Service1.

I bind IService to Service1 (im using ninject).

Can I have a .svc file that in the markup has...

```
Service="IService"
```

And tell wcf to somehow resolve that service and use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the .svc file is bound to the service type. What you can have is a route (if you use the ASP.NET Routes integration) where you, in code, resolve the IService binding to Service1 and add the route accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in the .svc file you can set Factory= to the class that you want to resolve the service.  I have not tried setting Service to an interface. If it does not work you can use an abstract base class for your  IOC.