# WCF Rest with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unity-container

I'm trying to use WCF REST Services and Unity (Enterprise Library 5), but can not find examples of how to implement the resolution of the services using Unity. I would like to call the registration of all interfaces and implementations for resolution in global.asax.

I'm using the following class to register the container:

```
public class DependencyResolver
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }\

    static DependencyResolver()
    {
        Container = new UnityContainer()
            .AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>()
            .RegisterType<IServiceDAO, ServiceDAO>()
            .RegisterType<IServiceBO, ServiceBO>()
            .RegisterType<IService, Service>();
    }
}
```

I searched but could not find enough examples, someone would have a code example with this solution applied?

I found some examples, like [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service/2455039#2455039) but I want the same context for all services. I want something like this http://entlibex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Service%20Behavior&referringTitle=Documentation but in my case I don't have a svc file.

Thank you.

Comment: Dependency resolver? Are you using ASP.NET WebAPI? or it's WCF 4 REST?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using WCF 4 REST? WCF 4 REST is a little bit out dated and hard to use.

I suggest you to use ASP.NET Web API (former WCF Web API). It's easier to use for REST service and with DI/IoC containers (in WCF you should write your own host, behavior etc.) as it has good built-in connectivity support for DI/IoC.

Here is example:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Comment: I can't, is a restriction of the project.

Comment: Unity is also restriction? Because Autofac has such funtionality already done "out of the box"

Comment: When Unity is also restriction than you should integrate WCF with Unity manually. Here is example of how to do it correctly: http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/15/Unity-dependency-injection-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-1.aspx, http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/17/Unity-dependency-injections-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-2.aspx. So you need your ServiceHostFactory, Behavior etc. But personally I will prefer Autofac.