# How do I pass parameters to a ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, service, parameters, servicehost

I am doing the following

```
 //Define the service host
        this._smeediPluginServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SmeediServiceHost), smeediServiceUri);
        this._smeediPluginServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISmeediServiceHost), GetBinding(), smeediServiceUri);
        SetupAndStartWebService(_smeediPluginServiceHost); 


  private void SetupAndStartWebService(ServiceHost serviceHost, ServiceDiscoveryBehavior serviceDiscoveryBehavior = null)
    {
        //Define service behaviours
        ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;

        //Add the behaviours to the service
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);

        if (serviceDiscoveryBehavior != null)
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDiscoveryBehavior);

        serviceHost.Open();
    }
```

I need to pass a parameter to the Service and I can't figure out how. I have looked at [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service) but couldn't get my head around it. Thanks

Comment: Could you just read from the app.config file using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[] within the service itself instead of passing to the constructor?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass parameters to the constructor of your service implementation class.  You can to this by [passing an *instance* of the service class to the `ServiceHost` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx), instead of its type.  That is:

```
// Create the service instance
var instance = new SmeediServiceHost("some parameters");

// Define the service host using the above instance
this._smeediPluginServiceHost = new ServiceHost(instance, smeediServiceUri);
```

**Caution** - using this approach means you are using a singleton instance of the service class.  If you need a new instance per session or per request, then consider using a `ServiceHostFactory` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2455039/1001985).

Comment: +1. As an addition, useful article: [WCF Service Instancing](http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/wcf-service-instancing)