# Setting variable from ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, servicehost

In my project, I have a service class.

```
class KLAService : IKLAService
{
    CentralLogic centralLogic;

    .....
}
```

Using this class, I set up the `ServiceHost` like this:

```
centralLogic = new CentralLogic();

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(KLAService));
using (host)
{ 
    host.Open();

    Application app = new Application();
    app.Run(new ConfigurationWPF.MainWindow(centralLogic));

    host.Close();
}
```

As it might have become clear, I create one instance of the `CentralLogic` class. This very instance is used in the UI but also in the host to manage other stuff in my solution.

The problem I'm having now, is to set the `centralLogic`-variable in the `KLAService`-class (or in the `host`). I don't know how to do this. I've read about the plugin Ninject and how to inject objects in the service, but that's way out of my league and I can't help but think there is an easy way.

How can I achieve my goal the best?

EDIT: Another solution proposed was to start the ServiceHost and let `CentralLogic` get created there instead of the other way around. That would mean the ServiceHost needs some sort of a constructor. I don't know what the best practice is nor how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need dependency injection. Since `CentralLogic` has a single instance, it is effectively a singleton. Read about singleton pattern [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

You can implement the singleton pattern on `CentralLogic`

```
public sealed class CentralLogic
{
    private static readonly Lazy<CentralLogic> lazy =
        new Lazy<CentralLogic>(() => new CentralLogic());

    public static CentralLogic Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private CentralLogic()
    {
    }
}
```

Then in the Service Impl's contructor (and in the UI), you get the instance, this way:

```
class KLAService : IKLAService
{
    CentralLogic m_centralLogic;

    public KLAService() 
    {
       m_centralLogic = CentralLogic.Instance;
       ....
    }
}
```

There is no need to pass anything to ServiceHost.

The most important thing for you here is make sure your CentralLogic's instance is thread safe.

Comment: This is more like it, I didn't understand why everything had to be so difficult. In the `ServiceHost`, how can I call the constructor? I'm having troubles with that. On the other hand, I don't really need a constructor which declares `m_centralLogic`, but could just use for example `CentralLogic.Instance.GetUsers();`. Let me try this one out.

Comment: You should not have problem with `KLAService` constructor - it is default (parameter-less) constructor after all - WCF will handle it. Yes, you can use - `CentralLogic.Instance.Methods()`  - please make sure all the methods and properties of the `CentralLogic` class are thread-safe in thier implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a singleton for the `CentralLogic` class.

If you want to do dependency injection, I would recommend [structuremap](http://structuremap.net) and you can set it up pretty easily with nuget and I'd advice for you to do the injection in the `KLAService`

Here's a console app that shows how to set it up and inject some local object to other classes:

```
class KLAService : IKLAService
{
    // Constructor injection
    public KLAService(ICentralLogic logic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(logic.Value);
    }

    // Manual instance creation
    internal void PrintLogicValue()
    {
        var logic = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ICentralLogic>();
        Console.WriteLine(logic.Value);
    }
}

interface IKLAService
{
}

class CentralLogic : ICentralLogic
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public CentralLogic()
    {
        Value = 12345;
    }
}

interface ICentralLogic
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logic = new CentralLogic();

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(scan => scan.TheCallingAssembly()));
        ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(x => x.For<ICentralLogic>().Use(y => logic));

        var service = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<KLAService>();
        service.PrintLogicValue();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When the code calls `var service = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<KLAService>();` the constructor expects an object of type `ICentralLogic` and the injector will provide the configured `logic` object.

Alternatively, you can manually get the configured object for `ICentralLogic` with `ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ICentralLogic>();`.

Comment: This makes sense. How would creating the `ServiceHost` fit in here?

Comment: The simplest approach is to change `new ServiceHost(typeof(KLAService))` with `new ServiceHost(ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<KLAService>())`

Comment: Ok, let me try this one out. Can you explain to me what you do with the two `ObjectFactory` lines? After that, you declare the `var service`. I could use that `service` in the `new ServiceHost...` line, correct?

Comment: `ObjectFactory.Initialize` initializes the structure map to scan the types of the calling assembly, ie, the current running app. The second line `ObjectFactory.Container.Configure` tells it whenever you need an instance with `ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance` you will get a the configured object. Your code would then become:
`ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<KLAService>());`

Comment: Singletons are good for a quick solution, and by no means, I've used them too in many projects. However, when you have to do unit testing configuring all the singletons will be quite a hassle. If you are planning on doing unit testing, I really would urge you to veer away from singletons, they're just too much of a headache to maintain and configure, especially if you want to write reusable code by others.