# Custom ServiceHost with DI and InstanceContextMode.Percall

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

In my Managed Application, I currently have my WCF services running as:

```
SomeService service = new SomeService(container) //IUnityContainer
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service, serviceAddress);
```

Whats the catch ? SomeService defined with:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single
```

This is not good anymore, I need to make it **InstanceContextMode.PerCall**.

When trying to .Open() If changing the InstanceContextMode to "PerCall" - it will throw:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: In order to use one of the ServiceHost constructors that takes a service instance, the InstanceContextMode of the service must be set to InstanceContextMode.Single.  This can be configured via the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.  Otherwise, please consider using the ServiceHost constructors that take a Type argument
```

Is this the solution to my problem ? [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

**My Main concern:**
I run different types of services inside this managed application, It seems that this solution is good only if i run one type of service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When more than one service instance will be needed (PerCall or PerSession) then passing a single service instance into the ServiceHost isn’t enough... which is the exception.

Controlling instance creation is managed by the [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx).

> Is this the solution to my problem ? [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

This only answers half your question. You are using Unity. The management of creating the container needs to be part of the implementation. The most common solution is to use [Unity.WCF](http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/) which is also available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Wcf) package.

Note that Unity.WCF doesn’t support object lifetimes based WCF OperationContexts. There are multiple (more complicated) implementations like [this](http://drewdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/07/unity-lifetime-managers-and-wcf.html) that do.

Comment: you mean i need something like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx

Comment: but what happens when i have many interfaces and not just one derived servicehost ?

Comment: Yes. Fabio Cozzolino's blog is what you need. Not sure what the "many interfaces" comment refers to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Many interfaces i mean services, i have ClientService, CheckService, all of them run locally and parallel.. i mean i have on my application different IService on different endpoints with same behavior, e.g localhost:7005/ClientService, localhost:7005/CheckService etc..

Comment: Do you know how i register the Service inside the container ? too bad he doesnt supply coded container registeration and he is using config file.. config file editing changes from version to version :(