# How to pass dependencies to a WCF restful service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am new to Rest services. I did fair bit of research on this topic but still not clearly understood. Hope someone clear this to me. Thanks in advance.

My client is going to execute a method on my service class through an url. All I understood is client going to call

```
localhost/service/get/customers
```

In my rest service I have dependencies like a `IRepository` so that I can go to database and fetch the records. If I go with constructor injection when would client call this constructor?

It looks like I need to use a service locator to fetch `IRepository` inside the method which I need it.

Doesn't this violate OOP principle? Is testing easy without DI?

Can anyone please clarify this.

For any service how do we expect client to know what is `IRepository` is what methods it does have? 
Is isn't it for internal implementation purpose Do we need t expose to the client? Why should he bother about it? Can't I provide just Uri Which method to call (localhost/service/Products) and job done.

I will appreciate if you provide any live example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've stumbled across a thorny issue: since it's the **WCF runtime** that will instantiate your WCF service class to handle the request, you **cannot** use constructor injection to resolve your dependencies. You'll have to find a way to let the WCF runtime create your service class, and then once it's created satisfy its dependencies. Some DI containers call this "post-creation injection" or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not violate OOP priciple, if you will resolve for dependency inside a method. But there is no need for that, you can use constructor Dependency Injection within WCF using [Instance Provider and ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), there is also good example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service).

If you are **self-hosting** the service, it will be even more simpler because it requires implementing only `IInstanceProvider` and `ServiceHost`. Assuming that you have `Service` service with constructor taking an `IDependency` parameter:

```
public class CustomInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
{
    private readonly IDependency dependency;

    public CustomInstanceProvider(IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // Here you are injecting dependency by constructor
        return new Service(dependency);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return this.GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }
    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }
}

public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public CustomServiceHost(IDependency dependency, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        foreach (var cd in this.ImplementedContracts.Values)
        {
            cd.Behaviors.Add(new CustomInstanceProvider(dependency));
        }
    }
}
```

Then when creating service, use `CustomServiceHost`:

```
var serviceHost = new CustomServiceHost(dependency, typeof(Service), uris);
```

Comment: Do I need to go through this much complexity when I am self hosting the service? isn't it overkill? Can you please give your opinion thanks

Comment: No, if you are self hosting the service, it will be a little simpler because it will require implementing only `IInstanceProvider` and `ServiceHost`. I provide an example.