# Accessing UI controls from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

In a plugin I'm creating in C# with .NET 4.0 for an existing third-party application, I created a thread to have a service listen on a named pipe.

In the function that I set as the `OperationContract`, I need to to call functions that deal with the UI, which sometimes create new UI controls downstream after they are called. Namely I get the following error:

"Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread"

I figured out that I should use a `BeginInvoke` from the `OperationContract` function to access the UI, but my problem is that I do not know from where I do get the object from which to call.  I tried quite a few (`this.BeginInvoke`, `Application.Current.BeginInkove`) but have not been able to figure it out, so I'm not able to even compile it.

The code below is the schema of the service that is created from a thread different from the main UI thread.  I need to know how to call BeginInvoke to run some code from the main UI thread from the function called OperationContractForService(string value):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

.
.
.

[ServiceContract]
public interface IInterfaceForService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string OperationContractForService(string value);
}

public class InterfaceForService : IInterfaceForService
{

    public string OperationContractForService(string value)
    {
        // .
        // Some code that may create controls in the UI in the main thread
        // How do I call BeginInvoke from here?
        // .
   }

}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library's methods are called from the UI thread, you can capture the current context like this:

```
var UiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Then you can launch your thread, and when you want to run code back on the UI thread, create a task and schedule it to run on the captured context:

```
Task t = new Task(() => 
                      //update UI
                  );

t.Start(uiContext);
```

Or better yet, create a TaskFactory with the above scheduled and use it to create new tasks whenever you need to update the UI:

```
TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(uiContext);

tf.StartNew(() => { ... });
```

Comment: I can pass the uiContext to the Worker class with the DoWork for the theead(which creates the ServiceHost and loops until a varible is set to close the thread, but I do not know how I can pass the uiContext to the InterfaceForService object that is created by the WorkerClass, because I'm not sure how I can access the InterfaceForServiceObject that is created by "new ServiceHost" or "host.AddServicePoint" (I do not know which one creates the InterfaceForService and how I can get a reference to the InterfaceForService object).

Comment: @Pep So you're using WCF? I believe you need to implement `IInstanceProvider`. This post will help you inject a value into your service implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the case, I'm using WCF and the service is created by the background thread (and kept alive for the life span of the background thread).

Comment: Yes it helped.  I grabbed the UIContext in the main thread, put it in a static variable of the service class and then started the TaskScheduler with the UI context. Thank you very much, I am a complete noob with C# and was overwhelmed by the complexity (perhaps I also contributed to the complexity by choosing to do named pipes IPC with WCF).

Answer (score 1):

You mention you've tried `Application.Current.BeginInvoke`, but you're missing a bit: it's `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. Does that work?

To be honest, though, I'd keep any knowledge of UI threads well out of your WCF layer. If something called by that OperationContract creates a UI element, let it call onto the UI thread itself.

If that's infeasible, I'd make your `InterfaceForService` capable of being told which TaskScheduler to dispatch onto, but make some other layer responsible for determining which TaskScheduler corresponds to the UI thread.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not feasible because I'm running plugin that is called at initialization by a third-party application, which owns the UI. At initialization time, I set up a service. Later on, when the service is called, I need to call functions exposed by the third-party application, which in its turn may need to create UI controls on the interface of the third party application (i.e. I do not directly create UI controls, that third-party application API calls may need to create them for me).

Comment: Aha, fair enough. In that case, you can capture the current SynchronizationContext on initialisation (as per @dcastro's answer), or use Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.