# Using Dependency Injection with Wcf Service Library working with WcfTestClient

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

After reading some info about adding Dependency Injection (for use with Unity) i still have one issue: WcfTestClient.

At this point of development i really don't want to install my Windows Service each time i hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, i just simply want to keep using the WcfTestClient (i think, or are there better ways?).

But the document explaining the way to use Dependency Injection with WCF services all mention '.svc' file... my project type (WCF Service Library) does not have a '.svc' file.

Sample documents:
 - [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service/2455039#2455039)
 - http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/usng-unity-with-a-wcf-service
 - http://orand.blogspot.nl/2006/10/wcf-service-dependency-injection.html

How can i use Dependency Injection with Wcf Service Library working with WcfTestClient?

Comment: Nope, during development i kept using dedicated constructors that provided all required dependencies and fixed this when wrapping it in a Windows Service.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i did not have found any way to achieve this.