# How to inject dependencies in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject a some business services in a WCF service. I read this really interessting post: [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

And I have done the following:

**Custom ServiceHost**

```
    public class UnityServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public UnityServiceHost(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
            }

            foreach (ContractDescription contractDescription in ImplementedContracts.Values)
            {
                contractDescription.Behaviors.Add(new UnityInstanceProvider(serviceType, container));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Custom Instance Provider**

```
public class UnityInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
{
    private readonly Type m_serviceType;
    private readonly IUnityContainer m_container;

    public UnityInstanceProvider(Type serviceType, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        m_serviceType = serviceType;
        m_container = container;
    }
    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }
    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return m_container.Resolve(m_serviceType);
    }
    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        (instance as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)       {       }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)     {       }


    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)     {       }
}
```

The service behavior that I've is looking like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior] 
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public ServerInformationService(ISomeDependency coreManager)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But I don't get into the `GetInstance`, and when I run the code, I get this:

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it
>   does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the
>   problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of
>   the type to the host.

What have I done wrong? It look like my instance provider isn't even used

Comment: This indicates that the dependency that you are trying to inject should have a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: @ArunGeorge  I don't think so, it event doesn't stop on the `return m_container.Resolve(m_serviceType);` breakpoint, I'm able to ask for the same exact service with the dependencies outside of WPF.

Comment: Is your service hosted in IIS? Are you using the `UnityServiceHost` class?

Comment: @YacoubMassad No, it's selfhosted. I finally found the issue. I was using ContractBehavior when I should have used ServiceBehavior. I'm confirming that everything is working and I will publish an answer

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. I was applying my InstanceProvider to Contact and not to services.

Here is my final (Working) solution:

```
public class UnityServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public UnityServiceHost(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
        }
        Description.Behaviors.Add(new UnityInstanceProvider(serviceType, container));
    }
}
```

And the behavior+instance provider:

```
public class UnityInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly Type m_serviceType;
    private readonly IUnityContainer m_container;

    public UnityInstanceProvider(Type serviceType, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        m_serviceType = serviceType;
        m_container = container;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher cd = (ChannelDispatcher)channelDispatcherBase;
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
            {
                if (!ed.IsSystemEndpoint)
                {
                    ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return m_container.Resolve(m_serviceType);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        (instance as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It works because I'm self-hosting the service(`new UnityServiceHost(...) ....`, if it was on IIS, I could not create the behavior that way