# How to pass common dependency to every WCF service instance

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm creating a WCF Host application. My Service class is defined as PerSession something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]   
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorInstance   
{   
    //...  
}
```

I assume that means that everytime a new session is created an new instance of the CalculatorService class will be instantiated. However if I have a common dependency that all the instance will depend upon, what is the best way to pass that dependecy to all the instances?

The `ServiceHost` class does not seem to have anyway to pass a "state" object to all the instances? Is there another way without using static variables or singletons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Injection. I haven't worked with WCF, but in WPF and UWP DI containers are used. Here is a WCF related article, written by Scott Hannen, on the topic.

http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/13/wcf-dependency-injection-in-5-minutes.html

Here is example provided by Microsoft showing DI in a UWP app. While the details might change, the concepts will remain the same.

https://github.com/Microsoft/InventorySample