# c# Namespace already contains a definition for inherited class so how to add a constructor

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor, asmx

I am carefully treading into WCF attempting to follow tutorials and convert my ASMX project to a new WCF project and I've stumbled upon a mystery about coding of my constructor in WCF.

My ASMX webservice allowed me to have a constructor (see: same name, no return value):

```
namespace sdkTrimFileServiceASMX
{
public class FileService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    Database db;
    string g_EventSource = "CBMI-TrimBroker";
    string g_EventLog = "Application";
    public FileService()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(g_EventSource))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(g_EventSource, g_EventLog);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My attempt to convert this to a WCF service app gives this compiler complaint:

```
The namespace 'sdkTRIMFileServiceWCF' already contains a definition for 'FileService'
```

Here is the WCF code (beginning snippet):

```
namespace sdkTRIMFileServiceWCF
{
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class FileService : IFileService                             // err msg points to this line
{
    Database db;
    string g_EventSource = "CBMI-TrimBroker";
    string g_EventLog = "Application";

    public FileService()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(g_EventSource))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(g_EventSource, g_EventLog);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you accidentally define you constructor twice?  Are you sure you didn't somehow use code generation that defines a second constructor?  [According to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381831/can-wcf-service-have-constructors), you can define constructors in WCF services, so that error is legit, and not a deficiency in WCF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't related to the existence of the constructor.  I am fairly sure this is a copy/paste error- perform a search for the word "FileService" in any files in your application and you will find another class or a namespace declaration with that name (in the same namespace).

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was my rookie fingers messing up with copy/paste into template-created items from my asmx items.

Answer (score 2):

Some things you could do:

- do right mouse click > Find references on FileService.
- Try a full search (ctrl+f) and search for FileService.
- Check any partial classes for a second constructor.
- Try clean solution and then rebuild the solution, see if this makes
  any difference.
- ...